# Java - How do I pause a script until a Variable has a specific value

Tags: java, scripting

I want to make java class Srcipt which is able to store scripts of code in each object. This code then gets executed when I call the play() method of the object. Also I want to write the code, so that it only executes lines 60 times a second and only when a variable isPlaying is false. And I want the solution to be efficient. So no while(isPlaying == true){} loops. I have different solutions, I can not find on here:

- Store lines of code in an Array of Strings and execute each one only when the Variable is false
- Similar to anonymous classes - change the play method to fit my needs
- Make another class Action with the method action(). I can then store them in an Array and with each one always use the anonymous class to change the action method.

Do you have a working solution?

Comment: Just make the class. I believe in you!

Comment: Create your class and when you get stuck on a specific feature, come back and post your code so far and we'll help you improve it.

Comment: In some ways that is one definition of object oriented programming. Objects are not just data, but also code which knows how to act on the data. Well, for some definition of "knows."